# how to add and remove css class on svg element

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I have a series of svg circles:

```
<svg id="pt124" class="marker aaa" style="left: 842.984px; top: 175.607px;"><circle style="fill: blue;" cy="10" fill="#CCCCCC" cx="10" r="4.5"></circle></svg>

<svg id="pt125" class="marker aaa" style="left: 553.565px; top: 106.903px;"><circle style="fill: blue;" cy="10" fill="#CCCCCC" cx="10" r="4.5"></circle></svg>

<svg id="pt126" class="marker aaa" style="left: 608.487px; top: 191.06px;"><circle style="fill: blue;" cy="10" fill="#CCCCCC" cx="10" r="4.5"></circle></svg>
```

I need to add a class "hide" to these objects.
I have tried several things without success:

```
$("svg#"+data[i]['name']).attr("class", "marker aaa hide");

$("svg#"+data[i]['name']+" circle").setAttribute("visibility", "hidden");

$("#"+data[i]['name']).context.hidden = false;
```

what am I missing?
How do I add the class to this?
THanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a class to *all* the circles, then you'd want something like

```
 d3.selectAll("circle")
   .attr("class", "hide");
```

This is equivalent:

```
 d3.selectAll("circle")
   .classed("hide", true);
```

Though I don't see where you're using `d3.js` specifically. The code you've provided uses `jQuery` syntax (`$(a bunch of stuff)`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this to add the class:-

```
$("svg#"+data[i]['name'] + ' circle').attr("class", "hide");
```

If you want to toggle the element you can do this:-

```
$("svg#"+data[i]['name'] + ' circle').toggle();
```